# what can i do to get all the selected names?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select Nom 
from Employes 
where Matricule = (select Matricule 
                   from Affectation 
                   where CodeFonc = (select CodeFonc 
                                     from Fonctions 
                                     where DesignationFonc = 'Chef Service'));
```

I'm executing this query in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

The execution results in an error

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Comment: What problem you are facing with this query?

Comment: You need yo do `where Matricule IN` in stead of `where Matricule =` and `where CodeFonc IN` instead of `where CodeFonc=`

Comment: You need to learn about **JOIN**s in T-SQL !

Comment: There better approach is to use JOIN

Comment: okay i'll see what i can do , thank you!

Comment: The error message is clear, your subquery returns more than 1 row, so instead of using `=` use `IN()`. Also if you include a sample data and desired results you may get better answers.

Comment: A `JOIN` or an `EXISTS` (with a `JOIN`) are definitely the right move here. Depends on if the relationship ship is one to many, or one to one/many to one. Impossible to know without sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Nom 
FROM Employes 
WHERE Matricule IN (
                    SELECT Matricule 
                    FROM Affectation 
                    WHERE CodeFonc IN (
                                       SELECT CodeFonc 
                                       FROM Fonctions 
                                       WHERE DesignationFonc = 'Chef Service'
                                      )
                   );
```